# Is my question appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question, but it might be to subjective. So, I thought I'd put it here and ask your opinion.

#### Question:

I want to know if there is *any reasons at all* **not** to use MySQL in this scenario.

> 2 servers behind a virtual IP with MySQL master-master replication

Goal: redundancy, want this to run 24/7

I have plenty of reasons why to use this <sup>(**1**</sup> I only want your most pessimist thoughts.

<sub><sup>(**1**</sup> We are using this already in an similar situation and are considering using something else for a new setup. We have access to s MSSQL cluster that are more than capable of handling the 24/7 demand.</sub>

#### Doubt:

The reason I'm hesitant to ask this question is that I have a hard time imagining how I would choose a *correct* answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *probably* okay if you elaborate on the

> I have plenty of reasons why to use this

part. You have reasons -- what are they? Perhaps share them with us?

Answer (score 4):

If your question is about the aspects of MySQL then yes, post it here, but like Jeff said, give us the reasons, don't hold back.

If it's about the aspects of the two servers configuration, or the aspects of the heartbeat configuration for failover redundancy, then no, it would be good on SF.